# Android emulator stop working after enable Launch in a tool windows option

Tags: android, android-emulator

After upgrade Android studio to 4.1.2 and enable the option of "Launch in a tool Windows" (Settings -> Tools -> Emulator) in my windows 10 machine, the emulator stop working.

The error i getting is:

```
The emulator process for AVD Pixel_3_API_29 was killed.
```

When i disable the "Launch in a tool Windows" the emulator start without problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you also have the [latest version of the Android SDK tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update) by going into Tools -> SDK Manager and then click on the SDK tools tab to check that every package has the latest version.

I would personally recommend sticking to using the emulator in a separate window until a new update since even when it works, the "tool Window" emulator still has some bugs and advanced options are yet unavailable.